# Easy vs. expert questions

Tags: discussion

What's a good way to deal with easy vs. expert? Right now pretty much all EOSIO users are new users. If we discourage all but expert-level questions, we may end up with a site which scares away the current user base. If we allow too high a volume of new user questions, we may not make it past closed beta.

Related: what's a good way for us to judge easy vs. expert?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not seeing any widespread problems; At this point, I think you are doing fine . Unless someone wants claim otherwise, I would try to avoid broad, hypothetical policy discussions unless something very specific becomes a problem in actual practice.

The goal is to create a diverse, comprehensive site. Unfortunately, you can't really "policy" a site into expertise if the community is not there. This site is barely one day old, but if you aren't seeing the types of questions that would intrigue folks in this space, you can balance that out by **inviting like-minded colleagues** who would likely have the types of questions *you* would like to see asked on this site.

Just a tip from your friendly neighborhood Community Manager.